# Batch file input phone number

Tags: batch-file, phone-number

I wrote a batch file to send a text message to the phone number `%number%`. (if your curios, it uses curl and the textbelt.com system).  I used a overly-complicated way for having the user input a phone number.  I restricted the characters to only numbers, automatically ten characters long, and automatically add dashes.

Here's my code:

```
:start
cls
echo Enter phone number:
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x1=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x2=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x3=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x4=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-%x4%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x5=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-%x4%%x5%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x6=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-%x4%%x5%%x6%-
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x7=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-%x4%%x5%%x6%-%x7%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x8=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-%x4%%x5%%x6%-%x7%%x8%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x9=%x% - 1
cls
echo Enter phone number:
echo %x1%%x2%%x3%-%x4%%x5%%x6%-%x7%%x8%%x9%
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set x=%errorlevel%
set /a x10=%x% - 1
set number=%x1%%x2%%x3%%x4%%x5%%x6%%x7%%x8%%x9%%x10%
cls
echo is this the correct number?
echo. %number%
choice /c yn 
set x=%errorlevel%
if %x%==2 goto start
```

As you can see, it is really long and complicated.  It works, but its what you call "*spaghetti code*".  I am willing to bet that there is a MUCH simpler way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use an external program, you can use editv32.exe (32-bit) or editv64.exe (64-bit) program to get input into an environment variable. Sample shell script (batch file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set PHONE=
editv32 -l 10 -n -p "Enter phone number: " PHONE
echo You entered: %PHONE%
```

`-l 10` limits input length to 10 characters, and `-n` allows only numeric input. You can download editv32.exe/editv64.exe from here: http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html (Copyrighted freeware)

Answer (score 0):

An idea :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cls
:start
set number=
for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do (
cls
if defined number echo !number!
echo Enter phone number:
choice /c 0123456789 >nul
set /a x=!errorlevel!-1
set  number=!number!!x!
)

echo is this the correct number?
echo. %number:~0,3%-%number:~3,3%-%number:~6,3%
choice /c yn 
set x=%errorlevel%
if %x%==2 goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use ReadFormattedLine subroutine in a very simple way; for example:

```
:start
cls
call :ReadFormattedLine number="###-###-####" /M "Enter phone number: "
echo Is this the correct number?
choice /c yn
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto start
echo The correct number is: %number%
```

This subroutine is written in pure Batch so it does not require any additional program, and it allows several formatted input operations, like read passwords, conversions to uppercase letters, etc. You may download it from: [Read a line with specific format](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5775.).

Answer (score 0):

My open-source `editenv` tool replaces my older `editv32`/`editv64` utilities:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv

Sample usage:

```
editenv -n 10 -a 0123456789 -p "Enter phone number: " PHONE
```

This command will display an `Enter phone number:` prompt and wait for input. Input length is limited to 10 characters (`-n`), and allowed characters are limited to numbers (`-a`).

Download here:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv/releases